# Child Interface with no methods

Tags: inheritance, design-patterns, interface

So I have an parent interface, and some other child interfaces, some have implementation, some others don't.

```
interface IParent {
    void A();
    void B();
}

interface IChild1 : IParent {
    void C();
}

interface IChild2 : IParent {
    // empty, just inherits
}
```

Is that good practice? If not, what's the better way to do it?

Comment: What do you want to achieve by introducing an interface without any new methods?

Comment: I have a interface with common methods for many child interfaces, but in this case the child won't have any specific method to implement. In other parts of the code, I'm always referencing the child interface, so not creating it would cause to reference directly the base class

Comment: Maybe provide examples of how you are using the child interfaces. If the empty interface is just to make your code more readable to you - OK, but its unusual and others reading your code might wonder :-).